# How can I detect the cell I have edited with bootstrap dataTables?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am working with editable bootstrap datatables. What I want to do is update the mySQL database when edited a cell:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable" class="stripe">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Elliott</td>
                <td>Beaty</td>
                <td>elliott@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Dirt</td>
                <td>Joe@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>John@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>4</th>
                <td>Jane</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>Jane@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5</th>
                <td>Billy</td>
                <td>Bob</td>
                <td>Billy@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>6</th>
                <td>Bobby</td>
                <td>Axlerod</td>
                <td>Bobby@axecapital.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/master/js/dataTables.cellEdit.js"></script>
<script src="basic.js"></script>
```

basic.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

    table.MakeCellsEditable({
        "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
    });
});

function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,row) {
    console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
    console.log("The old value for that cell was: " + oldValue);
    console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
    jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update.php",
       data: 'new='+ updatedCell.data(),
       cache: false
     });
}
```

update.php:

```
require('database.php'); 
$new = @$_POST['new'];
$pdo = $db->prepare("UPDATE data SET new=? WHERE id=?");  
$pdo->execute(array($update));
```

I have difficulties to find out what cell exactly I have edited. So when I change for example "Joe" to "Alan" I need the information that it is `id:1` and `row:First name`. I was wondering if dataTables already have variables for this information like for example `updatedRow.data()`.

---

One Addition:

the Console gives my the output:

```
[Log] The new value for the cell is: Alan
[Log] The old value for that cell was: Joe 
[Log] The values for each cell in that row are: 2,Alan,Dirt,Joe@example.com
```

So my idea is now to parse `updatedRow.data()` to get the id of the edited cell

Comment: `data: {new:updatedCell.data()},` instead of data: `'new='+ updatedCell.data(),`

Answer (score 1):

Change `data: {new:updatedCell.data()},` instead of `data: 'new='+ updatedCell.data(),`

like bellow :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST", 
    data: {new:updatedCell.data()},
    contentType: false,
}).done(function (ex) {
   //alert(updatedRow.data());  
   var final_data = updatedRow.data(); 
   var split_data = final_data.split(","); 

   alert("Id : "+ split_data[0] + "Email : " + split_data[3]);      
}).fail(function (ex) {
   console.log('failed');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But this is not giving me the information in what row the edited cell is.

Comment: I updated my question, because I just had an idea. The information I need for example, if I change `Joe` into `Alan` would be the id and the row. In that case, it would be `2` and `First Name`

Comment: because then I now i mySQL what exact cell I need to change there

Comment: alert(updatedRow.data()) gives me the output: `2,Alan,Dirt,Joe@example.com`. Now I only have to split the comma separated list and store the data separately

Comment: what is your expected output from `2,Alan,Dirt,Joe@example.com`?

Comment: `id="2"` and `row="2"` (for Alan). That gives me the indication that Alan is in the row "First Name"

Comment: are you want to only `2` from`2,Alan,Dirt,Joe@example.com`?

Comment: `var final_data = updatedRow.data();
var id = final_data.split(",");
alert(id[0]);` after done ajax request

Comment: yes, but also the position of the edited cell. Like for example when I edit `Joe@example.com` I need to know that it is in the row `Email`

Comment: I get an error message: `TypeError: final_data.split is not a function. (In 'final_data.split(",")', 'final_data.split' is undefined)`

Comment: Your solution indicates, that the user already knows that Email is edited. But  the cell that is edited is not predictable. So what I need to do is detect, which cell the user has edited